# Overwriting Constructor of a class from outisde

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, overwrite

So, the question is simple to aks:
How can I overwrite the constructor of a class from the outside. The Problem itself is, that i have a class which is already compiled, and it already has some constructors, but those idiots of coders removed a constructor, so i am now unable to XML(de)Serialize it...

So what they have done is this:
They changed
Vector2();
Vector2( x, y);
into
Vector2(x=0,y=0);

But my Problem is, that the Serializer isn't that intelligent to realize that he can still create the class, and changing the entire code would be a pain in the * * *

Comment: Bug report?  Ask them to put the empty constructor back in?

Comment: Perhaps the removed it for a reason?

Comment: Sidenote: A mutable reference type representing a 2D vector. That gives you some very strange semantics one wouldn't expect of a value-like thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inherit from it and provide the expected constructor yourself.

You can use deserialized instances of the derived class where your code expects `Vector2` instances:

```
public class Vector3: Vector2 {
    public Vector3(): base(0, 0) {}
}

// Your code:
Vector2 vector = (Vector3)XmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

Comment: @mlvljr - indeed, particularly if it's sealed.

Comment: @Seshiro - I've updated my answer to explain how you could use this technique to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

If by some chance the class was marked as partial, you can add it with your own partial class declaration:

```
public partial class CompiledClass
{
   public CompiledClass() { }
}
```